# Reference JSF managed bean property via EL in CSS resource

Tags: css, jsf, el

I have the following situation:

here is style.css where I import another css `@import "themes/theme1.css"; h1{color: var(--mainColor); }`

theme1.css looks like this `:root{--mainColor: #1D3557;}`

It would be a lot of themes. The main goal is that user can choose a theme, so that theme name (string) can be passed to a css dinamically.

Something like this `@import "themes/#{bean.getTheme}";`

Is it posible to get managed bean property value (or method) from CSS ?

Comment: can you provide more code?

Comment: which code, css, java or xhtml ?

Comment: css and xhtml if you can